# simplificar consulta MySQL de una subconsulta

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo una consulta para averiguar que trabajos no han sido facturados desde una fecha hacia atrás, tengo dos tablas facturación y trabajos, se vinculan por el id_trabajos, he probado así y me da resultado pero es muy muy lento.
llamar solo los q no han sido facturados.

```sql
SELECT tj.id_trabajos FROM trabajos tj  
WHERE (SELECT fa.id_trabajos FROM facturacion fa WHERE fa.fecha<'2021-05-31' AND tj.id_trabajos=fa.id_trabajos) is null
```

No soy muy experto y he probado otro sin resultado esto es lo que mas se aproxima al resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que yo veo es que estas haciendo una subconsulta, por eso tarda tanto, no veo necesaria la subconsulta si no hay un criterio especifico, si tu único criterio es que este en un rango de fechas y que no sea NULL, solo bastaría con un LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT * FROM facturacion fa LEFT JOIN trabajos ta ON 
fa.id_trabajos=ta.id_trabajos WHERE fa.fecha<'2021-05-31' AND fa.id_trabajos IS NULL;
```

Comment: estoy comparando las tablas facturación y la tabla trabajos, y obtengo los null (por que esos no están facturados), probando el código no me da nada, la idea es ver si el id_trabajos existe o no en la tabla facturación, si no existe lo arroja a la lista resultado

Comment: ok, modifiqué la consulta, intentalo ahora.

Comment: [Aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a956b0/6) te dejé un ejemplo para que lo revises, saludos.

Comment: Creo que el planteamiento es correcto, pero si interpretó al OP se deberían de invertir las tablas y la condición. Es decir puede existir un trabajo sin factura pero no una factura sin trabajo, de ahí que haciendo la consulta tal cual no le arroje resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Agradeciendo a Roberto por su apoyo y configurando su código a la necesidad requerida llegué a esto:

> SELECT ta.*, fa.fecha FROM facturacion fa RIGHT JOIN trabajos ta ON fa.id_trabajos=ta.id_trabajos
> WHERE fa.fecha is null or fa.fecha > '2021-05-30'
> ORDER BY ta.id_trabajos ASC

y con eso logre recopilar la info que necesitaba, es un poco complejo pero para mi resultado fue excelente.

Comment: De nada, estamos a vuestro servicio, saludos.